# SQL Query to get results from two conditions on column and a day on row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table look like:

```
Date       | ID
-----------+-----------
2015-07-01 | 10
2015-07-01 | 10
2015-06-01 | 10
2015-07-01 | 10
2015-06-01 | 10
2015-07-01 | 10
2015-03-01 | 10
2015-02-01 | 10
2015-07-01 | 10
2015-07-01 | 10
2015-03-12 | 10
2015-02-09 | 10
2015-07-05 | 10
2015-07-03 | 10
```

And I need the Month in rows and day in column, and I need send as parameter the first and last month to get

The result that I need look like this it need to count how many occurrences on that day happen for the month.

```
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
02    1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
03    1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
06    2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
07    6  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I think it is possible with "pivot "

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivot query. SQL Server has special syntax for this in the form of the `pivot` statement.  I generally prefer to use conditional aggregation:

```
select month([date]) as mon,
       sum(case when day([date]) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as day_01,
       sum(case when day([date]) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as day_02,
       . . .
       sum(case when day([date]) = 31 then 1 else 0 end) as day_31
from table t
group by month([date]) 
order by mon;
```

If you are not using SQL Server, very similar syntax works in most databases, although the functions for `day()` and `month()` might differ.

Also, you might also need to include the year in the aggregation, if your data spans multiple calendar years.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it using `PIVOT`:

```
select p.*
from (
  select day([Date]) as [Day],
         month([Date]) as [Month]
    from [Table]
) t
pivot (
  count([Day])
  for [Day] IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],
                [11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],
                [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])
) p
where p.[Month] between 1 and 12 -- adjust first and last month here.
order by p.[Month]
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a312f/1)